# Knockout Click event not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My click event in knockout is not firing why?

From the Html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: employees.pagedItems">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="text: id, click: $parent.openEditBox" />
                </td>
```

From the js:

```
var employeeViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.activebool = ko.observable(data.activebool);

    self.openEditbox = function() {
        console.log('2');
    }

}

var employeesViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.employees = ko.observableArray().paged(20);

    var employees = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (employee) {
        return new employeeViewModel(employee);
    })
    self.employees(employees);

    self.openEditbox = function() {
        console.log('1');
    }
}

var data = @Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model);
ko.applyBindings(new employeesViewModel(data));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARGH. it's a Typo "b" instead of "B" ... wasted another hour of my life removing ALL other code.

Anyways, for reference: before anything else: check for typos....

Where is the stackexchange forum to start the thread "the mental breakdown after discovering a typo after a lot of time wasted"?